# simplified and clean way to substitute variable values in JQuery id selector

Tags: jquery

In my application I have a mark up like these

```
    <div id="divLeft" style = " width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: left" onclick="DoThis('textId')"> 
          <input type="text" id="textId" />
    </div>
    <div id="divRight" style = " width: 600px; border: 1px solid red; float: right" onclcick="DoThat()">    
    </div>
```

and in the java script event handler code I have to retrieve textId element for which i use the id selector as

```
function DoThis(id){

//some code goes here
$("#"+id).show();
//some code goes here

}
```

and there are hundreds of places where am doing string concatenation like "#"+somID, this looks bad to me. I wanted to know is there some way or jquery selector API  like `$.id(someID)`  or something which would avoid this string concatenation?

Regards,
Jeez

Comment: Why do you don't want to perform string concatenation ? ` this looks bad to me.` Why ???

Comment: The real question is why are you using inline handlers at all. Unobtrusive JS is your friend.

Comment: @Boopathi, even i dont like string concatenation .. what do you suggest ?

Comment: usage of native javascript byId... posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper:

```
var $$ = function( id ) { return jQuery('#' + id); };

function DoThis(id){

    $$( id );

}
```

Comment: @JeeZ: you do concatenation here too.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid string concatenation, you could use the native function that is faster than jQuery css id selector.

```
jQuery.extend({
    byId: function(id) {
      return jQuery(document.getElementById(id));
    }
});

Usage and Possibility:
$.byId("foo").some_other_jQuery_method();
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeBt/

**Edit**:

You could also have something like the previous answer, using `$$` is cool ..

```
function $$(id) {
  return jQuery(document.getElementById(id));
}
//and
$$("foobar").html("Hey!. Im able to access it");
```

In this way, you will still get a jQuery object(array) which you can use in the same way as $("#"+id)